# Dual boot windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 & Broadcom Compatibility

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, hardware-compatibility

I have windows 8 pre-installed and also want to use Ubuntu (13.04) as my secondary OS. I had problems regarding Broadcom STA wireless drivers in 12.10, but the drivers work fine on older versions. How to dual boot Ubuntu and install Broadcom drivers after it.

Comment: This question has already been answered on the askubuntu site. The link to the answer is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289609/dell-3721-wifi-problem-ubuntu-13-04). Another thing, if your question applies to Ubuntu only, or you're looking for answers that are Ubuntu-specific, you should post it on the Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange site. See [Unix & Linux FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details.

Comment: I have already asked this question on that site but got no response on it.